# Module not found: Can't resolve 'node_modules/react' in 'C:\react-test\src\components\content'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows

I am completely new to React JS. I am trying to create an app and in doing so I changed the name of a folder. I made that change in Visual Studio Code. I changed the name from `C:\react-test\src\components\Content` to `C:\react-test\src\components\content`. So all I changed was the `C` into a `c`. Apparently that is enough to break my code because I am now getting the error:

> Failed to compile ./src/components/content/Content.js Module not
>   found: Can't resolve './node_modules/react' in
>   'C:\react-test\src\components\content' This error occurred during the
>   build time and cannot be dismissed.

This is what `Content.js` looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Content.css";

function Content() {
  return (
    <main>
      <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ToDo1" value="Navbar" /> Create a Navbar
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="ToDo2" value="Header" /> Create a Header
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="ToDo3" value="Main" /> Create a Main
        section
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="ToDo4" value="Footer" /> Create a Footer
        <br />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Content;
```

I have no clue as to how to solve it.

I have tried to change the rename back into `Content` in Visual Studio Code. That did not work. I also tried removing the `package-lock.json` file and the run `npm install` and `npm start`, as was suggested on an other internetsite. This too did not work.

Help is very much appreciated, because I am really stuck.

Comment: are you using create-react-app? sometimes when you make changes like this, you need to restart the dev server for it to pickup changes (`npm run start`)

Comment: Yes, I am using create-react-app. I did restart the server. I even rebooted the computer. But to no avail.

Comment: In _Cotent.js_, please show us your import statement for `React`

Comment: I edited my question to show the Content.js-code

Comment: Your import is correct. Did you try removing `node_modules` and reinstalling?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to remove node_modules. How do I do that?

Comment: You can right-click on the folder in VS Code or the file explorer of your operating system and choose 'delete' from the context menu. Alternatively, on Linux or macOS open the integrated terminal and type `rm -rf node_modules`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has caused me so much headache en cost me a so much time that in the end I decided to delete the whole project and start all over again. All of this makes think that I chose the wrong way to rename a file or folder. Can anybody explain what would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer worked for me. I'd try that bef

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.